# Properly exclude angular modules

Tags: angular, angular-module

I have an angular app where some features are exported to separate modules. This is because my clients can choose which features they want or doesn't want. For e.g. if one of the clients doesn't want a chat functionality, then I just remove the `ChatModule` from `app.module.ts`. Everything works fine, except that the `ChatModule` has a `ChatComponent`, which is included in root `app.component.html`, so if I only remove the `ChatModule` import from `app.module.ts`, the `<chat></chat>` tag remains in `app.component.html`. What is the best way of turning on/off these kind of modules without removing the tags from the templates?

**app.module.ts**

```
...
@NgModule({
    imports: [
       // ChatModule - module that I doesn't want to include
    ],
    declarations: [

    ],
    providers: [

    ],
})
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-content>
    <chat></chat> // Tag of the ChatComponent
</app-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Best Way would be:

1. First Creating a Separate Module Called: `SharedModule` (Or Something).
2. Then Adding the Shared Components to That Module. (In your case `ChatComponent`)
3. Then Removing the `ChatModule` wouldn't Arise Any Problems.
4. Then Create a `SharedService` in  `SharedModule` and create Variables for `ChatModuleIncluded` and others.
5. Finally **Show/Hide** `Chat` tag on `ChatModuleIncluded` variables Value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you don't have any other issues, you can use NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA(https://angular.io/api/core/NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA) like below.

> Using this schema, Angular won't throw a error stating element
>   matching `<Chat></Chat>` is not found.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // modiules
  ],
  declarations: [
    // components and pipes
  ],
  providers: [
    // providers
  ],
  exports: [
    // exports
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
```